# How to create a CMS page that is a sumbission form that when filled out generates an email?

Tags: cms, magento-1.6, contact-us

I am looking to create a CMS page and translate an application so that each field can be filled with a submit button that when hit, generates an email with the content of the application that was just submitted.

Is this possible within a standard CMS page or would there be outside development work involved on such a page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[You can easily add the contact form to the page](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/contact-form-in-magento/)

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" 
form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I am already using the Contact form block elsewhere and want to create a new submission form in a new CMS page with different fields that goes to a different email address can this be done?

Comment: Yes, but. Either you concat everything via JS so it fits the Validation and the variables your contactform mail sends or you just change the form_action and/or the template. Then you "just" have to implement your own controller (copy most of the code from Contact/IndexController